# How to modify default color when using ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground on CardView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, android-cardview

Here is my code on CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/item_home_device_card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation_raised"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:contentPadding="@dimen/padding_card">

...
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I don't have any clue to change default color, please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by defining your own selector drawable. Following are the contents of `selectableItemBackground`. Create a new drawable resource file and place this selector in it, and change it as per your need.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_focused" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

takes up the default color. In case if you want modify your custom color use a custom drawable for and include it in your cardview as below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:foreground="@drawable/custom_bg"/>
```

and for the custom_bg that you can see in above code, you have to define a xml file in drawable package. So on pre-lollipop devices you will have a solid click effect and on lollipop and above devices you will have a ripple effect on the cardview with custom background specified.